# Call checkbox in C# backend

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one checkbox with **ID=checkbox1** in Asp.net gridview. I want to use checkbox1 in if else condition in backend C# code.My problem is I am not getting how to call checkbox1 as it is not showing in the backend.

Thanks in advance.

My code is

```
if (txtsender.Text != String.Empty && checkbox1.checked==true)
{
     chklist();
}
```

Comment: add runat="server" to you checkbox code in the aspx page

Comment: Read about gridview events. Follow some tutorials, this is very basic and you will find many posts on web.

Comment: Post your aspx code.

Comment: @DIe runat=" Server" is already written

Comment: @PedroFernandesFilho HeaderTemplate>

                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" OnCheckedChanged="chckchanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
                                        Select All
                                    </HeaderTemplate>

Comment: @RahulSingh Sir it will be very appreciated if you help me in this.

Comment: An ID is case sensitive `CheckBox1 != checkbox1`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: the `checked` property is a boolean value, by the way.  The '== true' you have after it is unnecessary.

Comment: @PedroFernandesFilho in my backend page **checkbox1** is not showing

Comment: if the checkbox is within a gridview it doesn't exist on its own because there could be multiple versions of it. You have to find it within the gridview, possibly after an event occurs. Plenty of tutorials (and previous questions on this site) about how to access controls which are within a gridview. There's very little need to repeat it here.

Comment: Id's are case sensitive. you are calling "checkbox1" while your asp control is ID="CheckBox1". Please confirm.

Comment: We need more code to help you.

Comment: If you c# code are in um event method throwed by the checkbox, you can use the sender parameter to refer the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

One view to access your checkbox inside Gridview is to loop on grid view rows and find your checkbox. Code example given below to access gridview checkbox in button click event

Aspx code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" />
            <asp:TemplateField>                
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="T1" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" Text="Submit" />
```

Aspx.cs Code

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gv1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    CheckBox c = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkBox");
                    if (c.Checked)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```